# Is there a way of making sublime snippets with a regex trigger?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to make a snippet that is triggered by a regular expression. Is it even possible in Sublime Text 3?

I've tried this but it doesn't trigger. I've already checked that sublime replaces it correctly with the Find and Replace option.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[$1_$2
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>([a-zA-z])(\d)</tabTrigger>
<description></description>
<scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
</snippet>
```

> I want my snippet to be triggered by pressing tab after any word that matches a character followed by a digit and replace it with the character, a `_`, and the digit.

**Examples**

a1 turns into a_1

X0 turns into X_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger text for a `sublime-snippet` file has to be literal text in order to trigger; Sublime won't match it based on a regular expression. To do something like that you need a plugin command that is bound to the <kbd>tab</kbd> key (for example) that triggers a command that examines the text to the left of the cursor to see if it matches the regex and then expand it based on that.

I'm not aware of a general purpose package that does something like this (although [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) does this for expanding HTML tags, it's not generic and is known to interfere with regular tab completion) but there may be one listed on [package control](https://packagecontrol.io).

[This forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-snippet-question/44454) on the Sublime forum includes a sample plugin that does something very similar to this that may be useful as a starting point for something like this, though. Based on your examples above, it should do what you want as long as you swap the `scope` in the example for the one from your snippet so that it triggeres in LaTeX files instead of Markdown. You may want to rename the command as well in that case.

---

**[Edit]** If you're not sure how to use plugin in Sublime Text, [this video](https://youtu.be/lBgDilqulxg) covers how to do it.

Comment: What do I have to do to be able to use `sublime` and `sublime_plugin` imports?

Comment: @MaxWell Sublime provides them itself so you just need to save the plugin in the appropriate place and it will find them automatically. I added a link to a video that covers how to use plugins in Sublime if you're unfamiliar with that.

Comment: Yeah, that last comment helped a lot. It totally worked! Do you hace any other tutorials about the things you can do with plugins on Sublime ?

Comment: Furthermore, how can I make plugin trigger automatically but just inside LaTeX mathematical environments?

Comment: @MaxWell not yet, but it's one of the things I'm working on for upcoming videos on my YouTube channel. It may be possible to get this to trigger only inside of a math environment if there's a specific enough scope but I don't know a lot about LaTeX in general. It may be worth asking a separate question with some example LaTeX and the name of the package that you use for syntax highlighting (if any).

Comment: I solved the scope matter trying to make a snippet inside all the mathematical environments I use on LaTeX and pasting the scope sublime automatically gives  that's related to the environment on the key binding.

Comment: Now the only thing left for me is to automate it and quit the `tab` binding.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, maybe this expression,

```
(?i)(?<=<tabTrigger>[a-z])(?=\d<\/tabTrigger>)
```

replaced with `_` might be something that you might have in mind, for instance.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5dK5cE/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/5dK5cE/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---