# Remove $TM_CURRENT_LINE after inserting snippet

Tags: python, code-snippets, sublimetext4

Trying to create a snippet in sublime Text 4 where the tab trigger is `.print`

eg: `a.print` results in `print(a)`

The current code for the snippet is

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[print($TM_CURRENT_LINE)]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>.print</tabTrigger> -->
    <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

but results in `aprint(a)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of making sublime snippets with a regex trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540981/is-there-a-way-of-making-sublime-snippets-with-a-regex-trigger)

Comment: ( and follow the link there to https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-snippet-question/44454 )

Comment: Cannot resolve, I think this doesn't work with a snippet, think I need to create a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippets can only add a few code to the existing one, replacing the trigger. It cannot remove any current line. For that, I suggest you use plugins.